# Creating an error message when invalid login / signup

Tags: php, password-protection

I would like to display an error message when a user login is invalid (wrong password, etc.)

My current thought is that I would like to display the error message whenever the variable `$login_error` isset. Currently what I am attempting is looking like this:

```
        <section class="containerLogin">
        <div class="wrapLogin">
            <form onsubmit="return false" class="formLogin" class="loginForm">

                <?php
                if (isset($login_error)) {
                ?>

                    <div class="errorMessage">
                        There was an error - please try again
                    </div>

                <?php

                }
                ?>


                <div class="wrapInput">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email...">
                </div>
```

There is more input fields but I assume you get my point.

I thought I would be able to trigger the message if I set the variable to be true in my API but that doesn't seem to be the current case.

This is me establishing connection (function activated via onclick on button):

```
    <script>
    async function login() {
        const form = event.target.form
        console.log(form)
        let conn = await fetch("api-login", {
            method: "POST",
            body: new FormData(form)
        })
        let res = await conn.json()
        console.log(res)
        if (conn.ok) {
            location.href = "items"
        }
    }
</script>
```

me setting the variable to true in my API which validates the information

```
<?php

require_once('globals.php');


if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $login_error = true;
    _res(400, ['info' => 'email required']);
    exit();
}
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $login_error = true;
    _res(400, ['info' => 'email is invalid']);
    exit();
}
```

So brief sum:

*I would like to display an error message whenever a login attempt is invalid. I am having difficulties doing it and I am here for help :-)*

Edit: I have added my Globals file.

```
<?php

define('_PASSWORD_MIN_LEN', 6);
define('_PASSWORD_MAX_LEN', 20);


define('_USERNAME_MIN_LEN', 5);
define('_USERNAME_MAX_LEN', 20);


$login_title = 'Login';
$item_title = 'Items';
$login_error = true;


// ##############################
function _res($status = 200, $message = [])
{
    http_response_code($status);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($message);
    exit();
}


// ##############################
function _db()
{
    $database_user_name = 'root';
    $database_password = '';
    $database_connection = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mystore; charset=utf8mb4';

    $database_options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        // PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ];
    return new PDO($database_connection, $database_user_name, $database_password, $database_options);
}
```

Comment: If I set $login_error = true; In my file globals.php It will show as I actually set the variable.

Answer (score 1):

this has nothing to do with the problem but

instead of this

> ```
>             if (isset($login_error))
> ```
>
> you should do

```
            if ($login_error)
```

Comment: can you share complete code? js script, validation part and form

Comment: I would like to check if the variable is set. If the variable isset it should display the error message. That is why I am using it.

Comment: If they do as you say it'll throw an error if said variable isn't set, and as you said it has nothing to do with the question.